# Why do I get a compiler error, when applying the increment operator to a constant variable

Tags: c++

If I declare a constant variable

```
int const n=100; cout<<n+1<<endl;
```

The console shows the value as 101

but when I write a code like this:

```
int const n=100;
n++;
cout<<n<<endl;
```

There is a [compile time error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baead5bb3acd64c2):

> ```
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> main.cpp:6:5: error: increment of read-only variable 'n'
> ```

Is the second case different from the first case?

Comment: Why did you declare it constant if you were planning to change it?

Comment: The exact error message should be given.

Comment: @ederag It's pretty obvious what the _exact error message_ would be in case of trying to increment a constant variable. OP asks for the difference of incrementing and creation of temporary values like `n+1`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sure. Just recalling good practices for a new user. Having the exact message makes the question easily reachable by searching for the error message. Remember that SO is not a forum. Good questions are useful not only to the original poster.

Comment: @ederag Satisfied now?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Indeed, with the error message, and your new title, the question looks much clearer and useful. Downvote removed. No upvote because it does not *show* any research effort (e.g. links to relevant documentation).

Comment: @ederag Well, sure that's the purpose of edits, and how we can improve questions here. That's the good point that the site isn't a _forum_. Regarding the research efforts, feel free to find a good duplicate of that question applicable here.

Comment: Making an `int` as `const` tells the compiler that variable's value won't (or should not) change after initialisation.  Incrementing a variable involves changing its value.   Either the variable needs to be non-`const`, or there should be no attempt to change it.   Either way, changing a `const int` directly is a diagnosable error.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the second case different from the first case?

Yes they are fundamentally different.

```
int const n=100; 
n++;
```

The increment operator obviously cannot applied for a `const`(ant) variable, because the `const` keyword prevents it to be changed after the initial definition. That's why the compiler error is issued.

In the other case, the variable itself isn't changed, but another temporary value is created when it's passed to the `operator<<()` of `std::cout`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the compiler is asked to compute the output of adding a constant to an integer.  This causes no error.

In the second case, the compiler is asked to change the value of a constant.  This is illegal and results in a compiler error.